# Como passar uma variavel para blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho o seguinte cenário:
Alguns tipos de usuário podem ter acesso ao site, digamos USERTYP1,USERTYP2 ou USERTYP3.

O menu da minha aplicação muda de acordo com o tipo de usuário.

Tenho uma template master `homeMaster.blade.php` e o menu foi criado no arquivo `home.blade.php` que herda a template master.

No php tradicional deveria ter um `if` em `home.blade.php` para testar uma variável `$usertype`. De acordo com o tipo teríamos o menu apropriado.

Estava lendo a [documentação do blade](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#blade-templating) e criei esse código para testar o usuário:

```
@if ($usertype === "USERTYP1")
    menu 1
@elseif ($usertype === "USERTYP2")
    menu 2
@else
    menu 3
@endif
```

Eu não entendi como passar essa variável `$usertype` para `home.blade.php`, ou mesmo se essa seria a melhor abordagem para esse tipo de implementação.

--

Atualizando

Vou postar aqui para quem precisar.
Achei um [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247083/inheritance-template-using-blade) que responde exatamente a minha pergunta.

Comment: Você não consegue passar uma variável para a view, independente se ela é uma partial ou não, ou você não consegue passar uma variável de homeMaster.blade.php para home.blade.php? Seja mais específico por favor.

Comment: homeMaster é somente um template. Quem deverá tratar as condições é a pagina home.blade. Entáo devrá ser essa página que vai receber a variável, quando chamar a view.

Comment: Ou seja, como passar uma variável do controller para a view? foi isso o que eu entendi, me desculpe se não tem relação com a sua pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade eu estou iniciando com Laravel. Eu sei como passar a variavel do controller para a view. Mas eu estou usando - na minha view, etou extendendo da master view. Entao eu teria duas opcoes: 1- fazer os ifs dentro da view e chamar o @yield apropriado para aquele usertype ou 2- ter os ifs dentro do master. Nesse segundo caso eu teria que passar a variavel para o master. Mas estou concluindo que a melhor opcao - ou talvez a opao correta seja a abordagem numo 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode passar uma array quando você chama a view, como segundo paramento, contendo as variáveis que você quer usar na sua view. Exemplo:

```
view('home', ["usertype" => "USERTYP1"]);
```

Se você quer passar a variavel em uma chamada de include, você pode seguir o exemplo:

```
@include("home", ["usertype" => "USERTYP1"])
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode passar tambem usando o compact

ex:

```
public function edit($id) {

      $categorias = Categorias::all();
      $posts =  Posts::all();

       return view('edit')->with(compact('categorias','posts'));

}
```

e em sua view voce pode capturar esse valor normalmente

```
{{ $categorias }}
{{ $posts }}
```